# How do I combine rows in sql query and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, table

I have a large database that is connected to a forms mapping program. In order for me to map results from SQL queries I have to put a single line field in for each result row. It defaults to row 0 and if there are more than one result I need to manual change the index of the field to 1,2,3,4 etc... The current data I am trying to query is for a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|     Name      | Account Number | Accout Role 1 | Account Role 2 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| John Smith    |          12345 | TaxSigner     |                |
| John Smith    |          12345 |               | TaxOwner       |
| Tim Anderson  |         678920 | TaxSigner     |                |
| Tim Anderson  |         678920 |               | TaxOwner       |
| Bill Williams |         510301 | TaxSigner     |                |
| Bill Williams |         510301 |               | TaxOwner       |
| Frank Stevens |         897090 | TaxSigner     |                |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
|     Name      | Account Number | Accout Role 1 | Account Role 2 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| John Smith    |          12345 | TaxSigner     | TaxOwner       |
| Tim Anderson  |         678920 | TaxSigner     | TaxOwner       |
| Bill Williams |         510301 | TaxSigner     | TaxOwner       |
| Frank Stevens |         897090 | TaxSigner     |                |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

There could be some customers with a single role while others could have both. I am able to merge the duplicate rows into a single column but that won't work. I need each role to end up in a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `Name`
     , `Account Number`
     , MAX(`Accout Role 1`) `Accout Role 1`
     , MAX(`Account Role 2`) `Accout Role 2`
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY `Account Number` -- , `Name`
```